# *ngFor doesn't display data from API

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i am working in a school project. The front end is communicating with the API and the results are displayed in the browser console:

[Results displayed in the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42A9I.png)

this is the interface

```html
export interface Anuncios {
  id: number;
  AnuncioTipo: string;
  AnuncioAssunto: string;
  AnuncioDescricao: string;}
```

this is the ts file:

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AnunciosService } from '../../services/anuncios.service';
import { Anuncios } from '../../interfaces/anuncios';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {
  anuncios: Anuncios[] = [];

  constructor(public anunciosService: AnunciosService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.anunciosService.getAll().subscribe((data: Anuncios[]) => {
      this.anuncios = data;

      console.log(this.anuncios);
    });
  }


  }
```

this is the html file:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>Todos os anuncios</h1>
<a href="#" routerLink="/anuncios/create" class="btn btn-sucess">Criar novo anuncio</a>
</div>


<div>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let anuncio of anuncios">
  <p>ID: {{ anuncio.id }}</p>
  <p>Tipo: {{ anuncio.AnuncioTipo }}</p>
  <p>Assunto: {{ anuncio.AnuncioAssunto }}</p>
  <p>Descrição: {{ anuncio.AnuncioDescricao }}</p>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

[Results displayed in the application, it only shows the ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igaXC.png)

The application doesn't show the data collected from the web API, how can i fix this?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Can you share the `getAll()` method in `AnunciosService`?

Comment: getAll(): Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl + "Anuncio/ListAll")
    .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }

Comment: yes i am using VS code

Comment: Your console log shows lowerCase attributes, while you try to access attributes with capital letters

Comment: See that the result you received are in camelCase, "anuncioAssunto", not "AnuncioAssunto", the "interface" only help us to avoid errors, but **not** transform the response ::glups:: is the same comment before

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem is fixed! How can i mark this question as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API results in screenshot shows that the object keys are in **camelCase**, but your interface has them in **TitleCase**.

If that doesn't solve the issue then few other problems could be -

- The API is throwing error so the `catchError(this.errorHandler)` inside `getAll()` method is returning an empty array.
- The component or parent component's `ChangeDetectionStrategy` is set to `OnPush`. Although it should not create this specific issue here, but you never know.

First check whether there is an error in the `AnunciosService.getAll()` method. If none, then you may try using `async` pipe. That way you overcome the change detection and also closing the stream automatically against probable memory leak.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AnunciosService } from '../../services/anuncios.service';
import { Anuncios } from '../../interfaces/anuncios';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class IndexComponent {

  anuncios$: Observable<Anuncios[]> = this.anunciosService.getAll();

  constructor(public anunciosService: AnunciosService) { }

}
```

Template:

```html
<div>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let anuncio of anuncios$ | async"> <!-- use async -->
    <p>ID: {{ anuncio.id }}</p>
    <p>Tipo: {{ anuncio.AnuncioTipo }}</p>
    <p>Assunto: {{ anuncio.AnuncioAssunto }}</p>
    <p>Descrição: {{ anuncio.AnuncioDescricao }}</p>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface properties (in this case) need to match the properties coming from the API, they are all starting with lowercase (camelCase) from the API as seen in the console log.

try changing your interface to this

```
export interface Anuncios {
    id: number;
    anuncioTipo: string;
    anuncioAssunto: string;
    anuncioDescricao: string;
}
```

and your html to this

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let anuncio of anuncios">
    <p>ID: {{ anuncio.id }}</p>
    <p>Tipo: {{ anuncio.anuncioTipo }}</p>
    <p>Assunto: {{ anuncio.anuncioAssunto }}</p>
    <p>Descrição: {{ anuncio.anuncioDescricao }}</p>
</ng-container>
```